# C++11 array initialization with a non-copyable type with explicit constructor

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, initialization, noncopyable

I have a (third-party) class which is non-copyable.  I'd like to initialize an array of them.  Here's my best attempt:

```
#include <array>

class Thing
{
public:
  explicit Thing(int) {}
  Thing(const Thing&) = delete;
};

int main()
{
  std::array<Thing, 1> things{{{100}}}; // error here
};
```

GCC 4.7.2 says:

> error: converting to ‘std::array::value_type
>   {aka Thing}’ from initializer list would use explicit constructor
>   ‘Thing::Thing(int)’

OK, but that's exactly what I want--to use the explicit constructor.  How can I express that?  If I actually invoke the constructor myself, then I get an error about the copy constructor being deleted.  And I can't use `std::move()` because Thing is not movable (and I can't modify it).

The only alternative I've found so far is https://stackoverflow.com/a/15962814/4323 but this is undesirable because it's a bunch of extra code plus I need to cast the "storage" everywhere I use it (or keep a separate pointer to it, which adds indirection I don't want).

I want a solution that gives maximum performance when actually using the Things without a lot of ugly boilerplate.

Comment: You could add an explicit constructor that takes `initializer_list<int>` ?

Comment: The Standard says that for `std::array<T, N>`, `T` must be MoveConstructible and MoveAssignable

Comment: The solution in the linked thread doesn't look too painful. You have to have a level of indirection anyway (I don't think accessing `things[n]` for `std::array` is any different to accessing `things[n]` where `Things *things;` points into the storage that you placement new'd into)

Comment: @MattMcNabb: I expect it is different, because the address of the array itself is known at compile time, but the address stored in a pointer is probably not understood by the compiler in the same way.  I'd probably end up just casting the aligned storage to the array type at the call site (in a function of course).  I hadn't heard that the value_type of std::array must be movable...it seems to work just fine when not, so long as the value_type's constructor is not explicit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yet again, C++17's [guaranteed copy elision](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) comes to the rescue: an expression like `Thing{100}` no longer *creates* an object but merely specifies *how* some other object (your array element) is to be created.

Comment: Do you know of any compiler that can compile my original code now?  I tried a few things in https://godbolt.org/ (GCC trunk, Clang 5.0), but none of them worked, even with `-std=c++17`.

Comment: You do have to add the `Thing`: then you get https://wandbox.org/permlink/a6QUxzY3O0xN1GJ6.

Answer (score 1):

I tried adding the default move ctor and move assignment operator, changed the initialization a bit and it compiles:

```
#include <array>

class Thing
{
public:
  explicit Thing(int) {}
  Thing(const Thing&) = delete;
  Thing(Thing&&) = default;
  Thing& operator=(Thing&&) = default;
};

int main()
{
    std::array<Thing, 1> things {{ Thing(100) }}; // error gone
}
```

EDIT: I'd missed the "third-party" part. Sorry if this doesn't help :)

Comment: Yes, making the class movable fixes it, as does making the constructor not explicit.  But I can't do either, because it's not my class.  I guess I could wrap the class with one having an implicit constructor....

Comment: Adding a move constructor does not fix the case where the new[] operator is used. For example: `auto things = new Thing[1] { 100 };` will not work, and neither will `auto things = new Thing[1] { Thing { 100 } };`.

Answer (score -2):

You can use a `std::vector`:

```
std::vector<Thing> things;
things.reserve(1);
things.emplace_back(100);
```

or for just one element `boost::optional`:

```
boost::optional<Thing> thing;
thing.emplace(100);
```